# How to set timer on click?

Tags: android, kotlin, motionevent

Want to set timer on 1 minute, and if there were no clicks, then call my method `viewContract.lockScreen()`

Here is my code:

```
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    viewContract.lockScreen()
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
}
```

Comment: just clicks? or scrolls too?

Comment: @NaitikSoni clicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do a `postDelayed(...)` on a `Handler` like:

```
val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
val timerDuration = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1)
val timerAction = Runnable { /* call your method here... */ }

fun startTimer() =  handler.postDelayed(timerAction, timerDuration)
fun cancelTimer() = handler.removeCallbacks(timerAction)
```

**EDIT:**

It's a bit unclear in the question since you state that you want to execute `viewContract.lockScreen()` once the 1 minute has passed without interaction, but then you call the same method in `dispatchTouchEvent` which is when a touch occur. But as I see it, this would be how you should call it:

```
val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
val timerDuration = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1)
val timerAction = Runnable { viewContract.lockScreen() }

override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    cancelTimer()
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
}

fun startTimer() =  handler.postDelayed(timerAction, timerDuration)
fun cancelTimer() = handler.removeCallbacks(timerAction)
```

Also it's not really clear when the timer should start, but in any case, just call `startTimer()` when that should be happening.

Comment: i think that i can replace onViewClicked on my `dispatchTouchEvent`? Because here i can react on clicks

Comment: Updated the answer to a simpler `start/cancel` example, just call the `startTimer()`/`cancelTimer()` where ever you want to start and cancel the timer :)

Comment: The idea was to:
My method `dispatchTouchEvent()` responds to all clicks in the app.
And if the user stopped clicking and one minute passed i have to call `viewContract.lockScreen()`

Comment: Also if I understand correctly, it is better to call startTimer in the method dispatchTouchEvent. But it's kind of bad to call this method on every click, what do u think?